# Is it possible to install Microsoft office 2011- Mac version - in Ubuntu?

Tags: mac, microsoft-office

I have Mac Version of office 2011. Can I install that in Ubuntu 14.04LTS?

Comment: no i think it is not possible. You have to use Libreoffice. Read [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2083386)

Comment: The only feature I like in word is  good blogging with wordpress, I did not find good client in ubuntu(Trust me all try almost all of them), and all I have to do go into windows/MAC for my blogging and that is not possible as all of my development is in Ubuntu. Any solution?

Comment: I am already using libre office but its not doing helping me in blogging... copy paste is all messy I have to do reformatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not possible** because we don't have any good compatibility layer that supports MAC OS X programs well.  The closest, and only one would be [Darling](http://www.darlinghq.org/). Sadly, it can only run basic hello world programs. WINE does support Windows programs well, but not MAC OS X programs. So if you have the Windows version. You can run it in WINE.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew already answered correctly: "It is not possible!"

You can use the following Office derivatives, which are all Linux-compatible and not to bad in comparison to Microsoft Office:

- [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/)

[image]

<sub>Source: [libreoffice.org](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/libreoffice/)</sub>

---

- Apache [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/)

[image]

<sub>Source: [openoffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/product/index.html)</sub>